# Extract img tag source from string [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js

I have a string that looks like this

`<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3"><tr><td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO8iLLBmxFL2lvSfboTwwmH3yGF12PdsJe56rTAzJtbsFfS07I1YM_ZzavbwJREe7bUmhFR3ATyA" border="1"></td><td><ol style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><strong><li><a href="http://newsday.co.tt/2017/11/14/ansa-mcal-sends-5-containers-of-relief-items/" target="_blank">ANSA McAl sends 5 containers of relief items</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">Trinidad News</font></li></strong><a href="https://news.google.com/story/?hl=en&ned=us" target="_blank">Full coverage</a></ol></td></tr></table>`

What I would like to do is extract the source of the image tag. Any suggestions as to where to start to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), which is a very helpful method when trying to extract relevant data from a string:

```
'<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3"><tr><td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO8iLLBmxFL2lvSfboTwwmH3yGF12PdsJe56rTAzJtbsFfS07I1YM_ZzavbwJREe7bUmhFR3ATyA" border="1"></td><td><ol style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><strong><li><a href="http://newsday.co.tt/2017/11/14/ansa-mcal-sends-5-containers-of-relief-items/" target="_blank">ANSA McAl sends 5 containers of relief items</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">Trinidad News</font></li></strong><a href="https://news.google.com/story/?hl=en&ned=us" target="_blank">Full coverage</a></ol></td></tr></table>'
  .split('src="')[1]
  .split('"')[0]
```

Essentially, this does the following:

1. Splits the string into an array based on the substring `src="`
2. Splits the second item in that array into a new array, based on the substring `"`
3. Returns the first element in that array.

There are certainly other ways to do this as well (for instance, regex).

Comment: tried this but its not working I get an error stating res is not a function. The code is `var res = str.split('src="'); var test = res.split('"');` str is the string in the post above.

Comment: That's because `res` is not a function . It's an array. You need to select the strings you want from the array, as I've shown in the example.

Comment: Try `var res = str.split('src="')[1]; var test = res.split('"')[0];`

Probably can't hurt to have a look at [the methods on `String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype), either .